# Meaning of "sub + to + v " structure

Tags: meaning

"Biden to revive/boost U.S Pakistan relations"

What is the meaning of "sub + to+ verb" structure.

How is it different from.."Biden going to"

Comment: Hi Roy, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! This particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange instead.  In addition, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is less strict.

Comment: 'Biden going to revive ...' is possibly equally 'grammatical' in the murky regions of headlinese, but sounds less crisp and far less professional.